# view.removeFromSuperview() fatal error on a lot of taps

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I created my own slide out navigation menu, but when I tap a lot on a link menu, it causes an error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

It's on the slide panel animation:

```
func animateLeftPanel(shouldExpand shouldExpand: Bool) {
    if (shouldExpand) {
        currentState = .LeftPanelExpanded

        animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: CGRectGetWidth(centerNavigationController.view.frame) - centerPanelExpandedOffset)
    } else {
        animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: 0) { finished in
            self.currentState = .BothCollapsed

            self.leftViewController!.view.removeFromSuperview()
            self.leftViewController = nil;
        }
    }
}
```

At `self.leftViewController!.view.removeFromSuperview()` line, I don't understand why I get this error and how to solve it.

Comment: Test whether `self.leftViewController` is already nil instead of using force '!'?

Comment: @PhillipMills It is not nil, I don't understand if I click one time it works but if I tap a lot on the item it crash

Comment: @PhillipMills I just deleted the line it looks working

Comment: The error message doesn't agree with you.  :)  I suspect that somehow the function was being executed twice in a row with `shouldExpand` false.

Comment: @PhillipMills Yes the function is being called a lot of time if I tap on the link many times, but how to do if I tap on many times ?

Comment: Assuming it's not being called from different threads, I was suggesting `if let vc = self.leftViewController {
   vc.view.removeFromSuperview()
   self.leftViewController = nil
  }`

Comment: Someone has to write an article titled "Forced Unwrapping Considered Harmful". I've seen it abused both in the field and here on SO, more than I can count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
func animateLeftPanel(shouldExpand shouldExpand: Bool) {
    if (shouldExpand) {
        currentState = .LeftPanelExpanded

        animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: CGRectGetWidth(centerNavigationController.view.frame) - centerPanelExpandedOffset)
    } else {
        animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: 0) { finished in
            self.currentState = .BothCollapsed

            if let view = self.leftViewController!.view {
                view.removeFromSuperview()
                self.leftViewController = nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check also your animation block and keep in mind you can also do this before animation to prevent taps during animation:

```
self.leftViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

and in animation completion block:

```
self.leftViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Same thing if you use a button to expand that isnt in leftViewController.view: you can  disable it before animation and re enable it in animation completion block